# When receiving a document without an id field

Tags: mongodb

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/

The _id Field section describes as follows.

`If the server receives a document that does not have the _id field first, then the server will move the field to the beginning.`

If there is no id field, said to move to the beginning.

So, is it correct to operate as follows?

If you receive a document without an id field, create an id and set it as the beginning.

I'm confused. Please help me.

Comment: `_id` field is required for all documents that are in the database. It is also always the first field in the document. MongoDB will auto-generate `_id` if document to be insert doesnt have one. In case it has one but not as first field, it will move it to be first field.

Comment: @Takis It means moving if `_id` field is not the first. I understand, thank you!